# Django: do I have to provide list_display for admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

If I explicitly provide a `ModelAdmin` for a particular model in Django 1.8 admin, do I have to explicitly set the `list_display` member?

If I don't will Django use a default value for it (e.g. all fields except `id` in the order defined in the model)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to explicitly define `list_display`. If you omit it, a single column will be displayed with the `str(Model)` value. If you have a `__str__` funciton defined for your model (Python 3), that value will be returned, otherwise something like 'MyModel object'. This value will also be a link to your model form.

Therefore, I would say that it is a good practice to define the fields that you want to use.

Please note also that you cannot use fields in `list_editable` without them being present in `list_display`. This would give a:

```
SystemCheckError: (admin.E122) The value of 'list_editable[X]' refers to 'Y', which is not contained in 'list_display'.`
```